# Lithium Pouch Cell Expansion

Tags: batteries

I am planning to use the SPIM08HP pouch cells from batteryhookup.com for their crazy power. They have an extremely high discharge rate at 25c, but I have heard that under heavy load, pouch cells will start to build up gasses in the pouch and expand. Is there any way to prevent this other than pulling less current? Thanks!

Comment: Ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Only modestly informed opinion in this area: I'd expect that any reaction that liberated gas would not be a well controlled or controllable one or one that was properly reversible. I'd expect gas liberation to be a sign that you had pushed the system beyond its reversible limit and that you were seeing products of charge cycle degradation. I may be wrong :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon so what you are saying is that as long as I don’t pull all 200a, the battery should be fine?

Comment: @rexmatt 1. As above re what I know :-) 2. I'd love to see a data sheet - any links?
3. I'd not expect a reputable manufacturer spec a battery to a level where they had recoverable gassing, and certainly not to irrecoverable gassing. But, I may be wrong.

Comment: NB: " ... ALSO THESE ARE MORE SAFE THAN 18650 CELLS BECAUSE **WHEN THEY ARE SPENT** THE BAG EXPANDS. ..."  [**FROM**](https://batteryhookup.com/products/4-200a-lithium-polymer-3-7v-8ah-flat-pouch-cells-lipo-batteries)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Here is a link to the seller: https://batteryhookup.com/collections/lithium-polymer-lipo-cells-and-batteries/products/4-200a-lithium-polymer-3-7v-8ah-flat-pouch-cells-lipo-batteries They are used, and were made for an electric city bus, so they aren’t for sale brand new anywhere, nor was a datasheet released. They seem like pretty powerful cells though!

Comment: Useful discussion [here](https://www.diyelectriccar.com/forums/showthread.php/miata-conversion-using-18650-spim08hp-pouch-199105.html)

Comment: My comment above re gassing comes frrom the Batteryhookup.com site and the same blurb appears on their ads in several places. The gassing is "an end of life" indication. They say "60% off new"

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect that any reaction that liberated gas would not be a well controlled or controllable one or one that was properly reversible. I'd expect gas liberation to be a sign that you had pushed the system beyond its reversible limit and that you were seeing products of charge cycle degradation. I may be wrong :-).

> So what you are saying is that as long as I don’t pull all 200a, the battery should be fine?

1. As above re what I know :-)
2. I'd love to see a data sheet - any links?
3. I'd not expect a reputable manufacturer spec a battery to a level where they had recoverable gassing, and certainly not to irrecoverable gassing. But, I may be wrong. – >

NB: [**They say here**](https://batteryhookup.com/products/4-200a-lithium-polymer-3-7v-8ah-flat-pouch-cells-lipo-batteries):  "... ALSO THESE ARE MORE SAFE THAN 18650 CELLS BECAUSE **WHEN THEY ARE SPENT** THE BAG EXPANDS. ..."

My comment above re gassing comes from the Batteryhookup.com site and the same blurb appears on their ads in several places. The gassing is "an end of life" indication. They say "60% off new" –